# Why is adding a return statement for the main function in C important?

Tags: c, return

Why is adding a return statement for the `main()` function in C important if the programs I make runs the same without it?

Is there a disadvantage in my programs if I omitted the return statement in the `main()` function?

Comment: you might wanna check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: It's only important on SO ;-) (unless you want the prog to return a value to the caller which is commonly done on unix).

Comment: @const not really, that question is for C++ and this question is in C. I am not asking about the difference of `return` and `exit()`, I am just asking why I need to specify `return` in the `main()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by convention that you tell the operating system if your program exited successfully(`return`ing 0), or if there was an error(for example, by `return`ing an error code).

To remain more standards compliant, use `return EXIT_SUCCESS` or `return EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: Let's say that there two types of errors I want the computer to know, is it possible to `return 1;` to specify one error and `return 2;` to specify another error?

Comment: yeah, conventionally you can do that. and then get the error code returned to the operating system.

Comment: And you can customize actions to take in case a particular type of error occurs, and perhaps re-run the program after correcting the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to be **legal** (i.e. works on all compilers that support the standard), then if you've defined `main` as:

```
int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

It should return an integer. In this case, 0. Why? Because according to the standard, if you've defined a function to have a certain return type, it should return that return type. Otherwise, it just isn't legal.

**It may compile (thanks to forgiving compilers, and hence this should not be relied upon), but that doesn't mean it's correct.**

Comment: In C99, It __must__ compile for any standards-compliant compiler.

Comment: I up-voted your answer because of the last paragraph.

Comment: @exilonblack and unfortunately it was wrong in C99

Comment: @Bryan Chen you mean the "It may compile (thanks to forgiving compilers, and hence this should not be relied upon), but that doesn't mean it's correct." paragraph?

Comment: @exilonblack Yes. It compiles not because compilers are kind to you. But because the program is valid and should compile. you can rely on this behaviour (although I won't recommended it)

Comment: I do know that they're not kind, they don't have emotions. After reading all of these comments and replies, I decided to add `return` statements to make programs less problematic in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> The ISO C++ Standard (ISO/IEC 14882:1998) specifically requires main to return int. It has an explicit "shall" constraint upon well-formed programs. It shall have a return type of int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:

```
int main() { /* … */ }
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* … */ }
```

> But the ISO C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) actually does not mandate this as the C++ standard does. This comes as a surprise to many people. But despite what many documents say, including the Usenet comp.lang.c FAQ document (at great length), the actual text of the C Standard allows for main returning other types.

**You can use either the `int` or `void`.** Though, it is better to use the `int` returning because you should inform the OS how your program exited. See a practical example:

```
int main() {
  int a;
  printf("Enter a positive number: "); scanf("%d", &a);
  if(a<0) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if it is the best example, but it could help you understand the concept better. Hope that helps!